# ui-router, resolve, $http not working as documented

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have bug (or maybe wrong usage?) with ui-router, resolve, factory and *$http.get* call.

Here's a snippet of the code in the config section:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: './views/layout.html',
                controller: 'MyAppCtrl'
            },
            'app-navbar@index': {
                templateUrl: './views/app-navbar.html'
            },
            'app-accordion@index': {
                templateUrl: './views/app-accordion.html',
                controller: 'AppController',
                resolve: {
                    appPromiseObj: function (AppFactory) {
                        return AppFactory.getApps();
                    }
                }
            },
...
```

and have the following AppFactory

```
myApp.factory('AppFactory', function ($http) {
    var appFac = {
        apps: []
    };

    appFac.getApps = function () {
        promiseObj = $http
           .get('http://localhost:4567/applications')
           .success(function (data) {
             console.log("success calling http");
             angular.copy(data, appFac.apps);
        });
        return promiseObj;
    };
    return appFac;
});
```

But when I run the app, the console.log message in the 'success' callback never gets executed. The browser console log shows the http call executes OK with code 200. I am assuming this means angular thinks it has failed or should I be doing something else?

I even tried returning the $q promise object (as suggested in other somewhat related stack overflow threads) but no success. In the factory code if I use test data (i.e., no HTTP call) everything works fine even if I don't return a promise object. Any pointer on where the problem could be? Appreciate any pointers to help me debug...

Answer (score 0):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/phbQxyQhhRFLkzxaGV2H?p=preview). The problem was incorrect *promise* handling inside of the `AppFactory.getApps()`. We need to return the promise at the begining and then also return some adjusted stuff on success. Now it works...

This is the main change I made:

```
// INSTEAD of this

// appFac.getApps1 = function () {
//     promiseObj = $http.get('http://localhost:4567/applications')
//       .success(function (data) {
//        console.log("success calling http");
//        angular.copy(data, appFac.apps);
//     });
//     
//     return promiseObj;


// Let's use this

appFac.getApps = function () {
    return $http
      .get('http://localhost:4567/applications')
      .success(function (data) {
       console.log("success calling http");
       angular.copy(data, appFac.apps);
       return appFac.apps
    });

    // this is already returned above
    //return promiseObj;
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/phbQxyQhhRFLkzxaGV2H?p=preview)

EXTEND

Based on your extended plunker *(still not fully working as expected)*

-http://plnkr.co/edit/c89j3eFvYyguMt0QznAI?p=preview

I created adjsuted and workin version

- http://plnkr.co/edit/f2aucPcbtzqwIEogbjuJ?p=preview

The only changes was proper naming (*e.g. app.js to be loaded as a script instead of script.js...)*. But at the end, the promise is now resolved and this json:

```
[{"id":10566982,"networkID":34256899,"appID":56114114
  ,"name":"10566982name","description"
   ...
]
```

Is loaded and converted into accordion:

- 56114114name
- 58616695name

Finally to answer your question in the comment below:

> but what is the difference between promiseObj = $http(...)... ; return promiseObj and return $http (...);  ?

There is no difference *(except I see my approach a bit more clear)*. The real difference is:

```
angular.copy(data, appFac.apps);
```

vs

```
return appFac.apps
```

as a final statement of the **`.success()`** method. It MUST return something. tha's the trick

Comment: Radim - firstly thank you. I guess I am getting used to JS (being a Java programmer and all that) but what is the difference between promiseObj = $http(...)... ; return promiseObj and return $http (...); That said, the big difference I see is that you are returning the appFac.apps. When I try it locally it still doesn't seem to work. I now see that the call is succeeding but the console message still doesn't show (nor does the rest of the GUI :( ). I created a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/c89j3eFvYyguMt0QznAI?p=preview Any ideas?

Comment: Sir, I fixed your plunker and updated answer with more "answers". Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Radim - thanks the additional insight, really helps. This is my first end-to-end Angular PoC so lots of questions/learning for me!

Comment: Good. If that answers your question, do not forget to accept it. Good luck